# What is using up file descriptors?

Tags: linux, networking, files, file-descriptors

I have a problem where my application is crashing saying that there are too many open files.
running `lsof | wc -l` it says that there are 3447067 open file descriptors however I can't find out what is using that many file descriptors.

I ran `cat /etc/passwd` to find all users on the system followed by `lsof -u <user> | wc -l` for all those users, but I didn't even come near the amount of used descriptors.

Is there any reasonable way of determining what is using up so many file descriptors?

Comment: What are the active `ulimit` settings for the user running the program? Check with `ulimit -a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in /proc/[1-9]*/fd; do
    echo "$dir"
    cd "$dir" &>/dev/null || continue
    set -- *
    echo $#
    echo
done
```

This is the output of `lsof`. I do not know why it differs.

```
lsof -F p | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: I just tried that and I get a few that are around 100, and maybe one or two that are at 1000, but all in all there is not even close to the 3447076 that i get from `lsof | wc -l`

Comment: @munHunger Did you run that code as `root`? Maybe there are resources which are counted as file descriptors but not shown in `/proc/$PID/fd`. Sockets maybe. A different approach would be to count the entries per PID in the `lsof` output. But I don't have the time to do that right now.

Comment: Yes I did run it as root. I thought that sockets counted as normal file descriptors, but if not, where would they be listed(if at all)?

Comment: @munHunger See my edit.